# "No login found" error trying to log in at Area 51

Tags: support, area-51, login, stack-exchange-openid

I just signed up for an Stack Exchange account. I am trying to log in on Area 51, but I get a `No login found` error.

Specifically,

1. I go to https://area51.stackexchange.com/
2. I click on `log in` which is a link to [https://area51.stackexchange.com/users/login?returnurl=%2f](https://area51.stackexchange.com/users/login?returnurl=%2F)
3. I am redirected to [https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/login?returnurl=https%3a%2f%2farea51.stackexchange.com%2fusers%2flogin-or-signup%2fdelegated%3freturnurl%3dhttps%253a%252f%252farea51.stackexchange.com%26type%3dlogin&cdl=1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/login?returnurl=https%3A%2F%2Farea51.stackexchange.com%2Fusers%2Flogin-or-signup%2Fdelegated%3Freturnurl%3Dhttps%253a%252f%252farea51.stackexchange.com%26type%3Dlogin&cdl=1) that shows

   ```
   Completing log in to Area 51
   You will be redirected automatically
   ```

   (I am already logged in into my Stack Exchange account.)
4. I am redirected to [https://area51.stackexchange.com/users/login-or-signup/delegated?returnurl=https%3a%2f%2farea51.stackexchange.com&type=login](https://area51.stackexchange.com/users/login-or-signup/delegated?returnurl=https%3A%2F%2Farea51.stackexchange.com&type=login) showing

   ```
   Unable to log in with your OpenID provider: No user found
   Log in or Sign up
   ```

I get identical results using Firefox, Chrome, and Internet Explorer.

Comment: This appears to be a bug with the recent discontinuation of OpenID throughout the network. Area 51 hasn't been maintained in a *long* while; it's based on a fork of the software in its early days. Recently, in a push to remove OpenID there, they removed the login flow there and routed it through Meta Stack Exchange, this site. It appears that there's some sort of inconsistency there.

Comment: @SonictheWizardWerehog I mentioned in my answer that the user didn't joined Area 51 and needs to _join the community_ first. Also seems like a OpenID discontinuation issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot login because you need to *join* the community.
You cannot participate on Area 51 if you didn't **join Area 51**.
Creating an account on Stack Exchange does not create accounts for all Stack Exchange sites.
But when you join the community (or site), your profile will be copied over to the site and your profile will be linked to your Stack Exchange account.
You need to click <kbd>Sign Up</kbd> or <kbd>Join this community</kbd> then try  to log in.

<sup><strike>Note: Area 51 signup or join is broken according to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/323745/is-area51-login-broken) question.</strike> Area 51 signup is fixed</sup>

Comment: Yes, the "sign up" link seemed to work!!! Thanks!

Comment: A note from the future– clicking "Join this Community" from Meta.A51 did not work, and instead led to a "User Not Found" error page. I had to click the "Sign Up" button on A51 main in order to get it to go through.

Comment: It seems to be broken again