# Is Area 51 login broken?

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, login

Is Area 51 login broken? I tried to sign up today and this happened:

[image: Error message below]

```
Unable to log in with your OpenID provider:

An unexpected error occurred while logging in. It's not you, it's us. This is our fault.
Detailed information about this error has automatically been recorded and we have been notified.
```

To clarify, this is happening as soon as I click either the <kbd>sign up</kbd> or the <kbd>log in</kbd> buttons.

I never get asked if I want to log in with [OpenID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID) (I don't; I don't even have an OpenID), nor do I have any other way of influencing the outcome.

Comment: I have no problems logging in on all other sites (including this one), so I don't think that's it

Comment: Perhaps you're not logging in with OpenID on this site?

Comment: @RobertLongson What am I supposed to do to log in on Area 51 then? Because I don't know how else to do it. This is literally the page I got shown when I click on "log in".

Comment: I think the error is misleading and something is broken in the sign-up flow. Due to it being sunday, it might take 6 to 8 hours before an SE employee can look into this. I don't think this degradation of services warrants to get the on-call out of their bed for.

Comment: @rene I didn't expect a prompt response. If they fix it sometime next week it's fine.

Comment: @DenisNardin Sorry about the delay... Is this still happening?

Comment: @AdamLear Yes, the problem is still there.

Comment: @DenisNardin Thanks for checking. I see the error in our logs, will look into it.

Comment: @DenisNardin I *think* I fixed it, but I don't have a handy way to make sure. Would you mind trying again and letting me know if the issue persists, please?

Comment: @AdamLear It threw the same error, but afterwards I was logged in.

Comment: @AdamLear Also, no logout button appears and trying to look at my inbox generates errors, so I assume I'm not *really* logged in

Comment: @DenisNardin Yeah, looks like I made a couple wrong assumptions there. Digging further. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @DenisNardin Fix attempt #2 is in, if you want to give it a go.

Comment: @AdamLear Sorry, still no dice.

Comment: @AdamLear I cannot sign up still.

Comment: @AdamLear When this will be fixed?

Comment: @AdamLear When this will be fixed? It has been 1 month already from my 1. comment on this post.

Comment: @smileycreations15 Sorry about the delay. I finally had the time to get a local repro here and figure out a fix. It's currently in review and should go live some time early next week.

Comment: @smileycreations15 Area 51 does not get much attention and resources from Stack Exchange, it's been this way always. So I'll be really surprised if it really get fixed any time soon.

Comment: I’m voting to leave this open, as the area51 tag excerpt explicitly explains that these posts are on-topic here. If you want a change of this rule, start a new discussion.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Apologies again for the delay. I believe I have the real fix out in production now. Please let me know if you're still running into issues signing up on Area 51.

Comment: Still facing this issue now

Comment: Login/signup is broken again

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum that's the most minor edit I've ever seen, can you please explain what is wrong with blank space that you change it to the HTML entity? I'd roll it back if it would help, but please do not make such useless edits. Thanks.