# Login Issues at Area51

Tags: support, bug, area-51, login

I don't seem to be able to login to Area51. I tried many times but get the same issue:

[image]

The URL I am getting redirected to is: https://area51.stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/users/login-or-signup/delegated

I came across this: [Is Area51 login broken?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/323745) but the error message differed and this was some time ago hence I believe this might not be a duplicate.

Comment: I'm getting the same error

Comment: short update: I now have "This login is new to Area51", dunno if it worth a new question

Comment: I already have an account.

Comment: I do as well with some rep also.