# Can’t login to Area 51 ( Unable to log in with your OpenID provider: No user found)

Tags: support, area-51, login, user-accounts

[image]

I think I originally signed up with a Launchpad account, but looking at “My Logins” I see two accounts: a StackExchange one (used yesterday) and Launchpad (used Jun 28 ’18) so I suppose I created a new login when OpenID support was dropped. I’ve tried logging out and logging back in with both, clearing the browser cache each time, but I just get the same message.

Comment: Related/dupe: ["No login found" error trying to log in at Area 51](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319150/no-login-found-error-trying-to-log-in-at-area51)

Comment: So does this mean that effectively you can only use Area51 if you **don’t** have a StackExchange account?

Answer (score 8):

The solution (which wasn’t very clear to me in the linked discussion) is to choose **sign up** rather than **log in**. I was immediately logged in without doing any kind of sign up.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. All of other threads on this were worthless.