# I am a user but cannot register

Tags: bug, area-51, unregistered-users

Under Area 51 I am listed as an unregistered user - when I hit register it says 'unable to log in - no user found'.

Comment: Does this help? [Can’t login to Area 51 ( Unable to log in with your OpenID provider: No user found)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/324798) Are you clicking "Sign Up", or "Register"?