# Can't sign up into Area 51

Tags: support, area-51, sign-up

I wanted to propose a new site, so I went to https://area51.stackexchange.com/

If I click on the link "Propose a new technology site" then it shows:

> Area 51 >> Login Error
> Unable to log in:
> No user found

So I found out I first need to sign up into Area 51, but I couldn't see any link/button to do that.

Comment: If you're not logged in and you click on "Propose a new X site", it should redirect you to the SE login screen. If it doesn't, this seems like a bug.

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine: I don't think they previously had an account on Area 51. They were being redirected to the login screen as intended, but were met with an error because they hadn't *signed up* for Area 51 before.

Comment: Dupe I think: [Can’t login to Area 51 ( Unable to log in with your OpenID provider: No user found)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/324798)

Comment: @zcoop98: OP found out that they had to sign up, except they couldn't find the "sign up" button :)

Answer (score 12):

The "sign up" button is at the top of the page, next to "log in":

> [image]

I would agree that it's quite easy to miss, given the tiny font and low contrast.

Comment: That's it, for goodness sake, tell me that's on purpose... (the tiny font and minimal contrast)

Comment: You would almost think they don't want users to log in, sign up, chat or discuss on that site ....

Comment: @Joan Are51 is a bit of a forgotten corner and not getting the love from SE it might need. Don't be disappointed if a new site proposal falls flat.

Comment: @rene, I'm smelling that, done, not going to waste my time.

Comment: @Joan unless you have a vibrant community already, new proposals are unlikely to launch: see: [Changes to the Area 51 Process v3.0](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27938/changes-to-the-area-51-process-v3-0), so it is possible to get a new site started but the entry barrier went up a bit.

Comment: Also, regarding how the top bar on Area 51 looks right now: [The top bar on Area 51 is malformed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377733/335251)