# Area 51: Unable to log in: No user found

Tags: support, bug, area-51, login, user-accounts

When I click the (tiny) button to log in to [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com), it gives an error:

[image: Login Error]

I obviously have to have a user account to ask a question here, so this is definitely a bug. Could this be fixed so I can participate in Area 51? Thanks!

Comment: "Here" is Meta Stack Exchange, which is a different site. Area 51 has [its own meta site](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/), for what it's worth. I don't see an Area 51 account in [your network profile's list of accounts](https://stackexchange.com/users/18472697/ender?tab=accounts), which suggests you don't have an account on Area 51. The question linked by Jiminy Cricket should help you find where to sign up!

Comment: @Spevacus Yeah but I can't get into Meta Area 51 because I can't log in.

Comment: @JiminyCricket. Thanks, this does answer my question!

Comment: For some or other reason the comment and link have been deleted - [here it is again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/378768/cant-sign-up-into-area-51).

Comment: That is probably because I clicked (privately) that your link answered my question. Now the link is in the duplicate box above the question (and now in your new comment)!

Comment: Great, that makes sense, thanks. :)